# Show $b^Ty-x^*\leq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

The set up of the question is as follow,

$A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, $b$ is an $m \times 1$ vector, $x^* =\min_{x\in R^n}\|Ax-b\|_\infty$.

For any vector $v\in R^n$,  $\|v\|_\infty=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|v_i|$

$y$ is an $m \times 1$ vector such that $|y_1|+|y_2|+\cdots+|y_m|\leq 1$ and $A^Ty=0$.

I have proven that for any $u,v \in R^m, u^Tv\leq (|u_1|+|u_2|+...+|u_n|) \|v\|_{\infty}$.

I now want to show $b^Ty-x^*\leq 0$.

Here is what I get so far, first of all I have

$b^Ty-x^*\leq (|b_1|+|b_2|+...+|b_m|) \|y\|_\infty -x^*$ with  $\|y\|_\infty\leq1$.

Then, I rewrite $x^* =\min \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{mi}x_i-b_k$ after I assume k (where $1\leq k\leq m$)is the row in $Ax-b$ with the maximum value .

Then , I factor the $|b_k|$ term so that I get

$(|b_1|+|b_2|+...+|b_m|)\|y\|_\infty -x^*\leq (|b_1|+|b_2|+...+|b_m|)+|b_k|(\|y\|_{\infty}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{mi}x_i)$.

However, I am stuck after this. Although I think I have use the fact that $A^Ty=0$ here, I am not sure how to take advantage of it.I would appreciate if anyone could help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will first solve this problem for a norm that comes from an inner product. The answer to this very similar problem will give you an insight on to solve your actual problem. The conditions of the problem are exactly the same, but the norm comes from an inner product.

If you feel more comfortable with it, imagine it's the standard Euclidean inner product ($u^Tv$) and norm ($||\cdot||_2$)

The answer uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, in fact, the property that you mention:
$$\forall u, v\in \mathbb{R}^n, u^Tv \leq \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} |u_i|\right)||v||$$
is very similar to this inequality:

*$\forall u, v$ elements of an inner product space, the following inequality holds*
$$|\langle u, v\rangle| \leq ||u||||v||$$

*where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product (in our case, the scalar product of vectors), and $||\cdot||$ the norm induced by the scalar product of vectors.*

From now on, we will use the standard Euclidean metric version for $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$|u^Tv|\leq ||u||||v||$$

Now, as we have $x^* = min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}||Ax-b||$, then $\exists x_0\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $x^* = ||Ax_0 - b||$. Take $u = Ax_0 - b$ and $v = y$, what can you deduce?

> $$|(Ax_0 - b)^Ty| \leq ||Ax_0 - b||||y||$$ $$|x_0^TA^Ty - b^Ty| = |0 - b^Ty| = |b^Ty| \leq ||Ax_0 - b||||y||$$ As $||y|| \leq 1$, we have $$|b^Ty| \leq ||Ax_0 - b|| = x^*$$ Do you see how this inequality directly implies the desired inequality? (You can check it by evaluating all possible cases, if you do not see it inmediately)

Now, try to apply a similar reasoning for the infinity norm.

*Hint* → When we used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we actually only wanted to bound the scalar product of 2 vectors by a value dependent on $x^*$, how can we do the same? Given that you proved that $$\forall u, v\in \mathbb{R}^n, u^Tv \leq \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} |u_i|\right)||v||_\infty$$

P.S.: I used this specific format to answer your question to make you notice that many problems can be solved by looking at the solving process of a better behaved version of it.

Comment: It is very clear. I get it now, huge thanks!

Comment: I am glad! An upvote or defining this as the best answer would be dearly appreciated as a token of gratitude, though ;).